# display descending order column in datagridview.?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

how to display descending order in datagridview, the order must start from after last character.

this is my column in datagridview

ex:

1)ap20aa4779

2)ap09ss9999

3)se06ps1136

my desendeing order must start from after last character, im getting values from db.

it's like this

1)ap09ss9999

2)ap20aa4779

3)se06ps1136

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your code so we can help? There are many ways starting with adding an `ORDER BY` clause to your sql statement.

Comment: select TokenNo,VehicleNo,InTime from ScooterInOut where TokenStatus=0  i need descending order of vehicle after ending last char in VehicleNo... how can i get?

Answer (score 1):

To order by the last numerics of a string you should be able to do something like:

```
ORDER BY CAST(RIGHT(Sno, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', REVERSE(Sno)) -1) AS INT)
```

**EDIT:**

Added [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c7fe2/2/0) to demonstrate

Comment: hi bendataclear it's working grate on sql, but it's not working on ms Assess. i need in ms Access

Answer (score 0):

Change your `SELECT` statement to include a where clause.

```
SELECT SNo,TokenNo,VehicleNo,InTime 
FROM ScooterInOut 
WHERE VehicleNo like '%" + txtvehicleno.Text + "%' and TokenStatus=0
ORDER BY SNo
```